# Simplest possible oscillator (with some constraints)

Tags: analog, design, oscillator

I'm interested in finding an oscillator circuit that meets the following constraints:

- Runs on 9 volts or less
- Periodicity 100-1000 Hz or so
- Non-sinusoidal oscillation
- No inductors
- 1 transistor or diode
- Caps/resistors as necessary, as few as possible
- All components easily available, like what you'd find at Radio Shack

Why do I care about these constraints? I'm a weirdo. (Sinusoids are "prosaic". Inductors are "messy". 2 transistors is "cheating".)

I found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86377/why-does-this-circuit-oscillate), but is there something even simpler? (I think this is a sinusoidal oscillator anyway.)

Comment: -1 and you don't say why?

Comment: To put it more politely, the reasons you give for your requirements are not engineering reasons. So you are not asking about engineering, you are just making up a puzzle.

Comment: :-/ It's more than just a musing. I want to build one, and it would be a useful stepping-off point for building more complex circuits.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a complete circuit is required.

Comment: Where in the help section does it say a complete circuit request is off-topic? If you guys are going to be picky, you need to put a warning in your help section reading, "Warning: We're Picky". Don't have a help section that pretends to be inviting if the rest of you aren't going to be.

Comment: Simple circuit revisions or suggestions are certainly possible, but complete circuits or schematics aren't going to be something that *volunteers* will readily supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a unijunction (relaxation) oscillator e.g. 2N2646
[image]

See http://baec.tripod.com/DEC90/uni_tran.htm for design details

Answer (score 3):

Probably everyone knows about this 3-component oscillator- but it's hardly suitable for any serious application.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEqF5M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'm guessing that the cap charges, Q1 reaches the threshold voltage, and then it discharges, repeat. My question is how? Since current can't flow out of the base, I can understand it temporarily turning on, but then the base voltage would rise until it gets to 15-Veb. I'm obviously missing some trick with this setup.

Comment: @horta it's not really a trick- the EB junction will typically avalanche (reverse breakdown is usually around 9V) and give you an sawtooth at the capacitor. It's like using undocumented op codes - not a great idea except for entertainment purposes. Breaking down that junction also degrades the forward beta of the transistor so throw it away afterwards.

Comment: It is called a Esaki oscillator after its inventor Leona Esaki

Comment: @jippie I only see one non-tunnel-diode reference to that name, and it's another jippie post on ese.